# iTunes error like "You do not have enough access privilege for this operation"

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes

When i am trying to put the iPad HD app to iTunes for testing in iPad device i got an alert like this "You do not have enough access privilege for this operation ".How to resolve this issue?Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

[See this link](http://devimages.apple.com/maintenance/). May be this is the reason why you are not able to upload your app.

Some intruder have tried to access apple developers account information. That's why apple developers' site is down for maintenance. Just wait until they are finished up with maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably is due to the downtime of Apple developers site. XCode try to add the device to the portal but it can't. Ate the moment there is no solution until apple reactivate their servers.
The same error you are experiencing seems to happen to all the people trying to add their device to the portal through xcode.
Is that iPad already listed in developer portal?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to folder permissions. iTunes stores apps to this folder on your Mac

```
/Users/<username>/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/
```

If you do not have `write` permission you will not be able to add .ipa/.app files to iTunes to install on your device. Refer these links [MacOSX](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2963) and [Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419/en-us) to resolve issues related to permissions.

Alternatively, if you are using Mac, connect device to XCode and install the .ipa file from the XCode->Organiser on your device(s).

Hope that helps.